# Seeking hlep on an application of conditional probability

Tags: probability

The probability that a store will have exactly k customers on any given day is

$P_k(k) = \frac{1}{5}(\frac{4}{5})^K, k = 0, 1, 2, 3, ...$

Everyday, out of all the customers who purchased something from the store that day, one is randomly chosen to win a prize.

Assume that no customer visits this store more than once a day, and further assume that the store can handle an infinite number of customers.

The questions is:
What is the probability that a customer selected randomly from the population of all customers will win a prize?

What I do is:
1. calculate the probability: a customer randomly chosen win a prize, given there are exactly k customers that day.

P(win a prize | k customers) = $\frac{P(win \ a \ prize ,\ k \ customers)}{P(K \ customers)} = \frac{1/k}{\frac{1}{5}(\frac{4}{5})^K}$

because there probably are 0, 1, 2, 3, ....customer visits the store on a day. I add them together:

P(win) = $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1/k}{\frac{1}{5}(\frac{4}{5})^K}$

the result turns to be wrong, because the probability is larger than 1.

Thank you a lot if you can help correct my wrong answer. It would be better if you can give some comment.

Comment: What's the probability that a visiting customer buys something?

Comment: the question has no relation with buying something. I think just visit the store the customer will have a chance to win a prize.

Answer (score 1):

First, $P(\text{win} | k \text{ customers}) = \frac{1}{k}$ since each of the $k$ customers is equally likely to get the prize. Then, 
$$
P(\text{win}) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P(\text{win} | k \text{ customers}) P(k \text{ customers}) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} \left(\frac{1}{5}\right) \left( \frac{4}{5} \right)^k.
$$
As for a method to evaluate the sum, notice
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} \left( \frac{4}{5} \right)^k = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_0^{4/5}x^{k-1}dx = \int_{0}^{4/5}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{k-1} = \int_0^{4/5} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k
$$
Remember that $0 \leq x \leq 4/5$ so you can now apply the geometric series formula and get $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}$. Now you just need to put these pieces together to get what you need.

Comment: Which principle do you use to calculate P(win)? I don't understand the formula you use to calculate P(win). Thank you.

Comment: Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint events which partition the sample space. That is $A \cap B = \varnothing$ and $A \cup B = \Omega$. Then given any other event $E$ you have $E = E \cap \Omega = E \cap (A \cup B) = (E \cap A)\cup (E \cap B)$. Now $E \cap A$ and $E \cap B$ are disjoint events, so $P(E) = P((E \cap A) \cup (E \cap B)) = P(E \cap A) + P(E \cap B)$. Now, $P(E \cap A) = \frac{P(E\cap A)}{P(A)}P(A) = P(E|A)P(A)$ and similarly $P(E\cap B)=P(E|B)P(B)$. So $P(E) = P(E|A)P(A) + P(E|B)P(B)$. Now apply this to the partition of events being the number of customers in the store.